# insert json object into oracle db table blob column

Tags: php, sql, oracle, post, blob

The below is posting in dev console as **POST: 404**. I'm guessing my php is not correct. What am I doing wrong here?

On this JS side I'm doing:

```
    ........
    user = JSON.stringify(user); // updated Data, want to push to db table blob column
    pushData ();

    function pushData (){
        const ajax = $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `./Settings.php`,
            data: {obj_json: JSON.stringify(user) },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                //Write your code here
                console.log("data posted?");
            }
          });
        }
  .....
```

**/Settings.php** *(the class used has valid db connection, my `obj_json` is the column that is set to `blob` in db table). I am not really sure what to do with `$obj`*

```
class Settingz extends \myApp\Data
{

    public function insertBlob($obj, $last_update) {
        $obj = $_POST['obj_json'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(last_update,obj_json) VALUES(:last_update,:obj_json)";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':last_update', $last_update);
        $stmt->bindParam(':obj_json', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

        return $stmt->execute();
    }
  }
```

Comment: For one thing, you have `:obj_json` in VALUES, but binding with `:prefs_json`.

Comment: Whoops honest copy paste typo. Fixed now here in SO.

Comment: And that is why this comments area exists :-))

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner how do I handle it coming from POST? not filePath

Comment: You still have a typo `objs_json` with an "s".  Handling files is usually done with `$_FILES` in a form when done in pure PHP instead of `$_POST` and with an proper enctype. If this is JS or OOP related, I'm not the guy for this.

Answer (score 1):

With OCI8 you could use a Temporary LOB (see p.235 of [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html)), but with PDO_OCI, use a `RETURNING` clause like:

```
<?php


try {
    $db = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost/orclpdb1', 'cj', 'welcome');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("drop table cjblob");
$stmt->execute();

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $db->prepare("create table cjblob (id number, data blob)");
$stmt->execute();

function do_insert($db, $id, $data)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into cjblob (id, data) values (:id, empty_blob()) returning data into :blob");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':blob', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $blob = null;
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $stmt->execute();

//  var_dump($blob);  // $blob becomes a stream

    fwrite($blob, $data);
    fclose($blob);
    $db->commit();
}

do_insert($db, 1, str_pad("Z",  40000, "Z"));

// Fetch it back
$stmt = $db->prepare('select data from cjblob where id = ?');
$id = 1;
$stmt->execute(array($id));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($row);
var_dump(stream_get_contents($row['DATA']));

?>
```